# Finding convex envelope

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need to find largest $a$ such that $1/(ax+1)\ge g(x)$ for all $x$ in $[0,0.5]$. Both functions are convex, and $f$ is implicitly defined below. What is a good way to approach this in Mathematica?

```
expr = Assuming[{-1 < x < 1},  CDF[WignerSemicircleDistribution[1], x] // Refine];
f[x_] = expr;
g = InverseFunction[f][1 - #] &;
With[{a = 4}, Plot[{g[x], 1/(a x + 1)}, {x, 0, 1/2}, PlotLegends -> {"true", "bound"}]]
```

The brute-force approach is to call `Minimize` ([notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-envelope.nb)), for a 100 values in the interval but that's quite slow, 6 seconds per call. I guess Minimize doesn't utilize the convex nature of this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use calculus for this? For example:

```
sol = FindRoot[g[x] == 1/(a x + 1) && D[g[x] - 1/(a x + 1), x] == 0, {a, 4.5}, {x, .6}]
```

> {a -> 4.55481, x -> 0.0984177}

Visualization:

```
With[{a = Lookup[sol, a]},
    Plot[{g[x], 1/(a x + 1)}, {x, 0, 1/2}, PlotLegends->{"true","bound"}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, didn't realize `FindRoot` can take multiple equations